# Using array_push in method in php

Tags: php

The addRecipients use push_array but it does not work. What am I doing wrong here??

In class.emailer.php

```
class Emailer
{
public $sender;
public $recipients;
public $subject;
public $body;

function __construct($sender)
{
    $this->sender = $sender;
    $this->recipients = array();
}

public function addRecipients($recipient)
{
    array_push($this->recipients, $recipient);
}

public function setSubject($subject)
{
    $this->subject = $subject;
}

public function setBody($body)
{
    $this->body = $body;
}

public function sendEmail()
{
    echo "From sendEmail, send email initiated<br />";
    echo "Body: ".$this->body."<br />";
    echo "Subject: ".$this->subject."<br />";
    print_r ($this->sender);
    print_r ($this->recipients);
    echo "<br />";
    foreach ($this->recipients as $recipient)
    {
        echo "6<br />";
        //$result = mail($recipient, $this->subject, $this->body,"From: {$this->sender}\r\n");
        echo "7<br />";
        if ($result) echo "Mail successfully sent to {$recipient}<br/>";
    }
}
```

}

And in class.extendedemailer.php

```
include_once("class.emailer.php"); 

class ExtendedEmailer extends emailer
{
function  __construct(){
    //overwriting __contruct here   
}

public function setSender($sender)
{
    $this->sender = $sender;
}
}
```

And in sendemail.php

```
    include_once("class.extendedemailer.php"); 
echo "start 1<br />";
$xemailer = new ExtendedEmailer(); 

echo "1. adding sender: <br />";
$xemailer->setSender("sender@mywebsite.com"); 
print_r ($xemailer->sender);
echo "<br />2. adding recipients: <br />";
$xemailer->addRecipients("recipientemail@gmail.com"); 
var_dump ($xemailer->recipients);
echo "<br />3. adding subject: <br />";
$xemailer->setSubject("Just a Test<br />"); 
print_r ($xemailer->subject);
echo "4. adding body<br />";
$xemailer->setBody("Hi, How are you?<br />"); 
print_r ($xemailer->body);
echo "5. sending email<br />";
$xemailer->sendEmail();
```

The output of recipients is NULL.

```
start 1
1. adding sender: 
sender@mywebsite.com
2. adding recipients: 
NULL 
3. adding subject: 
Just a Test
4. adding body
Hi, How are you?
5. sending email
From sendEmail, send email initiated
Body: Hi, How are you?

Subject: Just a Test
```

Comment: public $recipients = array();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not initiating `$recipients` when you rewrote the constructor.

```
class Emailer {
    public $recipients = array();

    function __construct($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }
```

Should do it. Check your warnings for

> Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the parent's constructor from ExtendedEmailer's constructor.

```
class ExtendedEmailer extends emailer
{
  function  __construct(){
    parent::__construct(null); 
  }

  // ...
}
```

otherwise `$recipients` is never initialized as an array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're overriding the `Email` class's constructor and never calling it (`parent::__construct()`).  Either call the parent constructor in the `ExtendedEmailer` class constructor, or remove the constructor altogether from `ExtendedEmailer` if you're not actually using it (which in your sample code, you're not).

Answer (score 1):

You've missed to the call the parent constructor in the child's constructor

```
class ExtendedEmailer extends emailer
{
    function  __construct(){
        //overwriting __contruct here
        parent::__construct('dummy_sender@sender.com');
    }
}
```

should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in file "class.emailer.php" just do

```
public $recipients = array();
```

instead of just the kinda naked

```
public $recipients;
```

That's all, and as a sur-plus, you're free to fill up your constructors as you desire. - What do you think about that?

Regards, M.